# Append a string value to an exisiting json value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL. I'm trying to add a string value to a json value in MySQL. The column name is IPConfig. This is the current json string in the column.

```
{"theme":"black", "button1link":"http//sample.com", "name":"pp"}
```

I have to append a "www" to button1link value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Here you can try

```
UPDATE table SET DATA= JSON_SET(DATA, "$.button1link", INSERT("http//sample.com", 7, 0,'www')) WHERE 1 = 1;
```

But for this to work, you will need MySQL 5.7+

You can have [insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) function docs here.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. So i have a number of these values where i want to insert 'www' after 'https://' but the string after that is different. what would be a generalized solution for that. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It will just need http:// or http// or https:// or https//, not string after that. check these number of characters used, e.g. for https:// , write 9,0 instead of 7,0. It wont check for anything after https://, so no need to worry. For more details check insert function docs

Comment: awesome thanks! is it also possible to edit multiple columns in the same query for the same purpose. Like suppose there is a another json key like button2link.

Comment: I am sure you know how to write query to update multiple columns :)

Comment: UPDATE creative SET IpConfig = JSON_SET(IpConfig, '$.button1Link', INSERT('https://', 9, 0,'www.')) WHERE id = 1609606 ;

Comment: Hey so i get an error Unknown column 'IpConfig' in 'field list'. But the column IpConfig exists. Cant figure what else is the problem here.

Comment: IpConfig should be your json column, are you sure, its json column ?

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I resolved that issue. I get this message

Comment: FUNCTION xadcms.JSON_SET does not exist. I have a mysql5.6.31. Is there an alertnative solution to this then?

Comment: But for this to work, you will need MySQL 5.7+

I mentioned this earlier. 
Yes, there is.
You can create custom json_set function in mysql.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help on this. I figured out a way as the column I needed to edit was of text type. Thanks anyways!